# Remove filter without code change

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using ASP.Net Core API, I've below lines in startup.cs, is it possible to remove it without code change.

```
 services.AddMvc(opt => { if (!_env.IsProduction()) { opt.SslPort = 44388; } opt.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute()); });
```

As it always enforces HTTPs attribute. Please help.